# Custom html/link in a actionsheet button

Tags: html, hyperlink, uiactionsheet, ionic3

In my Ionic 3 app. I need to put a link inside a action sheet button. I cannot open a download link programmatically because it will throw the opening a popup/other window, which will compromise the user experince.

How could I add a link inside a button of a action sheet?

Comment: What do you want to do with link in action sheet button? Explain `I cannot...window`.

Comment: The browser will block the popup window. The user can unblock, but in many cases it's not clear enough how to unblock.